# When I use GET on my website it's ok but when I use Postman no result

Tags: angular, symfony, get, postman

When I launch a GET request with Postman, I have a 200 response so I don't understand why the request doesn't register in my database and when I go to my website with the GET request it's working fine but not with Postman.

Exemple:

https://i.gyazo.com/24e66cedfa2dbb3e7ca388c73d89fe73.png

Maybe because of the headers content?

```
  addDonneesEau(id: number, voltage, niveau_eau, vitesse, datetime, date, heure): Observable<DonneesEauModel> {
    const body = { voltage, niveau_eau, vitesse, datetime, date, heure };
    console.log(body);
    return this.httpClient.post<DonneesEauModel>(`${environment.baseUrl}/capteurs-eaus/${id}/donnees-eaus`, body);
  }

  addValeurEau() {
    this.receptionService.addDonneesEau(
      this.capteurId,
      this.Voltage,
      this.niveau_eau,
      this.vitesse,
      this.datetime,
      this.date,
      this.heure,
    ).subscribe(
      () => this.registrationFailed = true,
    );
  }
```

The app is deveveloped with Angular 5 and Symfony 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Do you see request on your network ?
- If you put 'dump('test')' in top of your action in Symfony, do you see it as request response on your network ?

if both have yes answer is may cause by content type who are application/json by default, this can result error by traditional way to get request parameter in symfony.

instead of doing :

```
$request->get("myParam",1)
```

you have to do :

```
        $params = json_decode($request->getContent(),true);
```

Where params will have followed structure :

```
{ voltage, niveau_eau, vitesse, datetime, date, heure };
```

Comment: So the problem is not with Angular ? Thanks for answer, i transfer your answer to the dev back end

Comment: if answer for my both question are yes, is 100% sure is backend issue. Please close this topic by validate my answer if is good from your side.

Comment: i wait the response and if is yes i close this topic :)